# JSON Array from String

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I have an array of JSON plots which I store in MySQL.  When I retrieve this information from MySQL it is given as one long string.  How can I restore this back into an array of JSON objects using Javascript?  I'm running this using NodeJS and MySQL package.

My data is returned like the following:

```
'[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":1,y:1},{"x":2,"y":2}]'
```

What I would like to be able to do is use the data like:

```
var data = [{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":1,"y":1},{"x":2,"y":2}];
console.log(data[0].x);
```

I've had a try using JSON.parse and originally stored the data using JSON.stringify on the array, but it is not behaving as I would expect.

Are there any methods or packages available to handle this?

Edit:  I realize now that this is not JSON but rather objects.  Apologies for the wrong terminology here, but my problem still remains.

Comment: That isn't JSON.

Comment: In JSON, quotes must be double quotes, and all property names must be strings (e.g., in quotes), so this is not json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var data = new Function ('return ' + dataString)();`